# How can i prevent an tabulator-popup-container from auto-hiding on a click event outside of the popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

Im using tabulator to display a large data set, and loving it. However, my dataset and table have a lot of options (filtering, expanding, editing, etc.). To guide new users i'm building a onboarding-tour with shepherd.js. When im displaying the custom filter popup (.tabulator-popup-container) i want people to be able to click  "next step of the tour". But this gets prevented because the click results in the popup auto-hiding. and then my shepherd step is replaced (makes sense, the target is gone) and then you have to click again.

Now, i want to prevent the auto hiding to be able to click throught, and hide the popup programatically once you activate the next step. I now how to get rid of the popup element (simple element remove action). But i cant figure out how to keep the popup from hiding. Ive tried addind a stopPropagation on the clickevent or mousedown. so far, no luck. Please help!

As said, I tried the standard js actions to prevent the propagation. But no luck so far. Also tried to list all the eventListeners to get to the one forcing the hide on blur, but i could find the responsible listener.